# bottom navigation view inside fragment only shows after click

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have a bottom navigation view inside of a Fragment, the help i need is that when i open the "main fragment" i want the first bottom navigation view shows insted i have to click or navigate for the ui shows thank you!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_places, container, false);

        new EuropeFragment();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    return rootView;
}


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_europe:
                        selectedFragment = new EuropeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_asia:
                        selectedFragment = new AsiaFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_africa:
                        selectedFragment = new AfricaFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_america:
                        selectedFragment = new AmericaFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_oceania:
                        selectedFragment = new OceaniaFragment();
                        break;

                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Post your mainFragment code

Comment: why is it not your activity that integrates the bottom navigation view?

Comment: I think your code is incomplete please refer tutorial : https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Your main fragment  is not being set in the first place. In the navListener, inside the onNavigationItemSelected() method, you've set the selected fragment in the container. But initially, you haven't set anything. So, inside your Activity class, you need to set the main_fragment using fragment transaction code.